# How to use unique pointers to create matrix?

Tags: c++11

I have to create a matrix using unique poiters that permit operations: Matrix a,b; Matrix c(b) and Matrix d=a;
So far I did the simple implementing of a matrix

```
class Matrix
{
public:vector<vector<int>> data;
    Matrix() {}
    Matrix(vector<vector<int>> matrix)
    {
        this->data=matrix;
    }
    Matrix (const Matrix& m2)
    {
        this->data=m2.data;
    }
    Matrix& operator= (const Matrix &m2)
    {
        this->data = m2.data;
        return *this;
    }
}
```

It's first time for me facing unique_ptr vectors, I found a plenty of informations about unique_ptr vectors creating arrays, but not much for matrix, it's so unclear.
How can I use unique_ptr vectors(I must use them) instread of simple vector?
Any help is welcome, thank you!

Comment: As written, your constructors and assignment operators are redundant, as the default implementations will do the right thing. If you absolutely must wrap `int`s in `unique_ptr`s (which is bonkers), then you _will_ need those operators in order to implement **deep copying** yourself. I'm sure you can search to find plenty info on that. Did you try any changes to reach your goal yet? What problems did you face?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for init matrix only with std::unique_ptr [1]:

```
const int rowCount = 3;
const int clmnCount = 6;

std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<int[]>[]> matrix(new std::unique_ptr<int[]>[rowCount]());
// or
// auto matrix = new std::unique_ptr<int[]>[rowCount]();

for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    matrix[i] = std::make_unique<int[]>(clmnCount);
```

Example of use [1]:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    const int rowCount = 3;
    const int clmnCount = 6;

    std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<int[]>[]> matrix(new std::unique_ptr<int[]>[rowCount]());
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = std::make_unique<int[]>(clmnCount);
        for (int j = 0; j < clmnCount; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = j;
            std::cout << std::setw(3) << matrix[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Or if u want use std::vector of std::unique_ptr try this [2]:

```
const int rowCount = 3;
const int clmnCount = 6;

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int[]>> matrix;

for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    matrix.push_back(std::make_unique<int[]>(clmnCount));
```

Example of use [2]:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    const int rowCount = 3;
    const int clmnCount = 6;

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int[]>> matrix;

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        matrix.push_back(std::make_unique<int[]>(clmnCount));
        for (int j = 0; j < clmnCount; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = j;
            std::cout << std::setw(3) << matrix[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope I understood correctly that you want todo